# Rails find someones birthday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a birthday problem. I'm trying to find all users who have a birthday 5 days from now.

I can do something like the below but the year is causing problems..

```
@dobs = Time.now + 5.days
@users = User.where(dob: @dobs).all
```

I also tried to make the dob.year the current year but this breaks for birthdays in early Jan because 5 days earlier is the year before.

Is there a gem I can use, or is it something more obvious?

Comment: can you give an example of how it breaks for early Jan ?

Comment: Is `dob` a `date` or a `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
User.where(dob:  (Time.now + 5.days).all_day) 

User.where(dob:  (Date.today + 5.days).all_day) # or as Qwertie suggested
```

`all_day` will capture anything from the start to the end of the day.

Comment: Could also use Date.today which has no time.

Comment: Sidenote: it is impossible to know who would be born 5 days from now and regardless of how advanced our children are these days I can reasonably assume that they would not be users of a website just yet.